# Same required field validator for 2 textboes?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation, required

My application is in mvc 3
I am having two text boxes with values "mobile number" and "Home number" . The custemor is required to enter any one field. If he entered any one  number , no need to show any required filed error message. The "phone number is required" should be shown only if both the fields are empty.

How is this possible.
Can anybody please help me
Thanks in advance
Vidya

Answer (score 0):

You can try your own validation, not the perfect one but this works,

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstField, new { @id = "FirstField" }) 
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.SecondField, new { @id = "SecondField" })

<small><p id="errorMsg"></p></small>

<input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn" />        

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.btn').click(function () {

                if ($('#FirstField').val() == '' && $('#SecondField').val() == '') {
                    $('#errorMsg').html('Please provide value in any one Field');
                    return false;
                }

            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: did you try my answer ?

Comment: try putting an alert() inside the ` $('.btn').click(function () {` to check whether the control comes in